# HTMX interaction with checkboxes

Tags: flask, htmx

First time user of HTMX here, experimenting with HTMX and Flask by making a classic quick todo app. However, when I have a checkbox that is **checked**, I can never seem to access the value from the hx-post request (i.e. by `request.form.get("complete")`). Minimum example of the problem:

```py
@app.route("/complete", methods=["POST"])
def toggle_complete():
  todo_id = request.form.get("complete")
  print(f"todo id: {todo_id}") # will give 'None' when sent from a 'checked' checkbox case.
  todo = db.session.execute(db.select(Todos).where(Todos.id==todo_id)).scalar()
  todo.complete = not todo.complete
  db.session.commit()

  # For this example not using any of my todo values/information, just have this example where it should toggle checked and not checked.
  if todo.complete:
    return f"""
        <div class="row todo-item">
          <div class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input checked value="1" type="checkbox" name="complete" hx-trigger="click" hx-post="/complete" hx-target="closest .todo-item" hx-swap="outerHTML">
          </div>
        </div>
  """
  else:
    return f"""
        <div class="row todo-item" data-todo-id="1">
          <div class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input value="1" type="checkbox" name="complete" hx-trigger="click" hx-post="/complete" hx-target="closest .todo-item" hx-swap="outerHTML" >
          </div>
        </div>
  """
```

Does 'checked' interfere with 'value' somehow? Or perhaps I'm missing something obvious, seems like odd behavior. Appreciate any help, full code [source here](https://github.com/ACHolmes/flask-todo) :)

Tried: removing 'checked' and I never get errors. The two cases alternate, and work as intended barring the fact that the checkbox is always unchecked. Anything I do with checked (adding it there manually, using f-strings to put it there) seems to break my code.

Comment: You can omit the value attr and instead attach the todo id to your post url (as part of the path or query value). You also don't need the hx-trigger. I think htmx does catch `changed` event by default on checkbox. I know it's not the solution to your problem, but it does the job without handling the form values. Lmk if that's a sufficient solution and I can provide code snippet in the response.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll give that a try, thanks! I'll give it a go and reply back here with result :)